# PHP Regex does not react how I would wish

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP Regex to see if a pattern is in my string. Simply put, I want one of two words followed by a number. So, here's my pattern:

```
#(guitare|piano)[0-9]#
```

Basically, if the string contains the word "guitare", I don't want it to be matched, only if I have "guitare9" or "piano0"

At this point, If I use this pattern for the follwing string:

```
J'aime la guitare9
```

The array of the preg_match() returns guitare and guitare9: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7tZ

What do I have to change in my regex to only match guitare9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn capturing group in your regex to non-capturing group. Because `preg_match` would display the match and also the captured strings in an array. By turning capturing group into non-capturing, you must get a single array element.

```
#(?:guitare|piano)[0-9]#
```

[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7u0)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I had to wait 9 minutes and I forgot !